# Self-sizing table view cell is not working with ExpandingTableView.framework Library in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want a self sizing table view cell to work in the following. I have four labels in one cell. All the labels will have long contents.

Right now, the problem is - if the second label has more contents, then all the below labels go invisible.

Refer Screen-1 I'm using ExpandingTableView.framework library (github.com/jozsef-vesza/ExpandableTableView) from Github. I've attached the project below.

Screen 1
[image]

#### [Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzolC8EgXkB1UERJQlJraEFKMWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please post your code or, if you're adding constraints from XIB/Storyboard, a screenshot with all the activated constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked into your code and fixed issue. Couple of things missing there are listed out below
In your 'MainViewController' add this below code, we actually don't need this code you can ignore if you want. Issue was totally with constraints.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat  {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}`
```

In your main.storyboard file couple of constraints were missing.

1) Add `bottom` constraint for 3rd UILabel in TableViewCell

2) Change `Main title label` height constraints relation form `Equal` to `Greater than of equal`

Will work like a charm :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this !!! The other thing i forgot to write is that I want the 'View Photo' cell should get automatically closed if other 'View Photo' cell is opened. Is it possible?

Comment: Hey.. its already working i guess expanding tableview is already handling it. At any given point of time only one cells 'view photo' is opened